# How to eat/gobble all following skips?

Tags: spacing

Is there a way to gobble all following skips? The opposite is possible with `\unskip`. I have a custom chapter layout (done in `memoir`) using `tikz`, and, for instance, the list of figures uses `\addvspace` to separate figures of different chapters--but if there are no figures in the first few chapters, there are a few `\addvspaces` piling up in the beginning, leaving me with an unwanted space.

If you were to look at the beginning of the *.lof file, there would be in case of `memoir`:

```
\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\select@language {english}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\select@language {english}
\addvspace {0.5\onelineskip }
\addvspace {0.5\onelineskip }
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {2.1}{\ignorespaces The...
```

Note the two `\addvspace` lines before the first `\contentsline`.

The following MWE reduces the problem to its essence, so it doesn't directly involve the LOF. The gray area shows the area where my chapter style puts the chapter title stuff. I did not include that, and I made the area gray to show the transition to the text after the chapter title area.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={framed, inner frame sep=0pt,
         background rectangle/.style={fill=gray}}}

\newcommand{\testchap}{
    \noindent%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfresetboundingbox
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, -5cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \par\nobreak\ignorespaces%  TODO: how to eat all following skips??
}

\begin{document}

\testchap
\addvspace{.5\baselineskip} % this should be without effect
\lipsum*[1-3]

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Is a solution possible?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking: what's the connection with the table of contents?

Comment: I'm not so sure why you are asking this... I never mentioned the table of contents, but the list of figures. Anyway, after my chapter definition I do not want any skips to be effective, neither in case of a following `\section`, nor in case of the list of figures if it starts with a few `\addvspace`'s. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Yes, I confused TOC and LOF. The question is unclear anyway.

Comment: Can you give me a little more detail about what information you need or what exactly is unclear to you? All I want to know is how to do the opposite of `\unskip`: neutralize a following `\addvspace` or `\vskip`.

Comment: the image you show is of greyed out space in the body of the document, but your problem description is about list of figures which isn't used in your example?

Comment: I see what you mean. I thought to reduce the problem to its essence in the MWE... I will add some more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after much research I found a working solution, even though it seems like a hack to me. The idea is to define a boolean `\after@chapter` that says "we are after a chapter, do not `\addvspace` here".

`\addvspace` then uses that boolean and only adds space if it is false.

Finally, I redefine `\@afterheading` and reset that boolean when the next paragraph starts (using `\everypar`), so that in case there was no immediate `\addvspace`, they still work further down the text.

```
\newcommand{\testchap}{
    \noindent%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfresetboundingbox
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, -5cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \par\nobreak\global\after@chaptertrue%
    \ignorespaces%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newif\ifafter@chapter
\after@chapterfalse

\def\addvspace#1{
    \ifafter@chapter
    \else
        \ifvmode
            \if@minipage\else
                \ifdim \lastskip =\z@
                    \vskip #1\relax
                \else
                    \@tempskipb#1\relax
                    \@xaddvskip
                \fi
            \fi
        \else
            \@noitemerr
        \fi
    \fi}


% no newlines in here! (\ExplSyntaxOn takes care of that)
\def\@afterheading{
    \@nobreaktrue
    \everypar{
        \ifafter@chapter
            \global\after@chapterfalse
        \else
            \everypar{}
        \fi
        \if@nobreak
            \@nobreakfalse
            \clubpenalty \@M
            \if@afterindent \else
                {\setbox\z@\lastbox}
            \fi
        \else
            \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
            \everypar{}
        \fi}}

% this is specific to memoir: a section starts with \sectionblock.
%     Define it to unset afterchapter, and don't add interlinespace.
\newcommand{\sectionblock}{
    \ifafter@chapter
        \global\after@chapterfalse
        \nointerlineskip
    \fi
}
```

Obviously, this only works with `\addvspace`, a simple `\vspace` would still add its space. Also, I had to add a memoir-specific hack and define `\sectionblock` since `\@startsection` says in its definition `\if@nobreak\everypar{}`, effectively ruining my code :)

Last, I don't understand why I had to use `\global`. `\@nobreakfalse` and friends don't need it either?!

Comment: The definition of `\@nobreakfalse` is `\global\let\if@nobreak\iffalse`, and similarly for `\@nobreaktrue`. The same for `\@minipagetrue`/`\@minipagefalse` and a couple of other inner conditionals.